# Using SQL with VBScript in ArcPad 10?

Tags: sql, arcpad, vbscript

I am trying to get a count of related records (Tableform) in order to validate Editform entry (using VBS).

Any help getting myCount?

I Know there are some syntax issues here, but is this even possible in Arcpad axf?

Seems simple using VBA but something like this:

```vb
Sub Validate()
    myCount = (Select count(*) from tblRelatedRecs where ID = Pcontrol.value Group by ID   
    If myCount > 5 then
        Application.MessageBox ("Huma, you erred!")
        ThisEvent.Result = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to execute a SQL expression. I believe (and I could be wrong here) that data stored in an AXF file can only be queried in such a way.

Have a look at this [How to use ArcPad with SQL - Part 2, UPDATE](http://arcpadteam.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/how-to-use-arcpad-with-sql-part-2_08.html) blog. You can find more information about querying DataSource objects and what they return in the [ArcPad Developer Help - Concepts](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcpad/10.0/sdk/scripting/).